# Не добавляется текст в textarea с помощью append

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, img

Реализую добавление картинки в новость и смысл таков: при добавлении картинки на сервер - записывается сразу значение в текстовое поле, чтобы она в будущем вызвалась.
Код добавления: `$('textarea[name=full_text]').append('&ltbr&gt&ltbr&gt&lt;img src="/files/img/'+filename+'" alt="'+filename+'"&gt;');`
Код, который должен получиться: какой-то текст + ⟨br⟩⟨br⟩⟨img src="/files/img/'+filename+'" alt="'+filename+'"⟩.
Код не добавляется, а просто заменяет весь текст, при том, что в коде это выглядит так, а в реальности, как видно в самой форме, сидит лишь текст, который был записан ранее, также он только и добавляется в базу.
Собственно, весь код:

```html
<?php
    if (!session_id())
        session_start();
    require_once('../functions/functions.php');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $intro_text = $_POST['intro_text'];
        $full_text = $_POST['full_text'];
        $img_url = $_POST['img_url'];
        $result = addArticlesAdm($title, $intro_text, $full_text, $img_url);
        
        
        
        if ($result) {
            echo '<script>alert("Новость успешно добавлена!")</script>';
            exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /admin'>");
        }
        else
            echo '<script>alert("Ошибка добавления новости.")</script>';
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ДС "Зоренька"</title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <meta name = "keywords" content = "Оцифиальный, сайт, МБДОУ, ДС, Зоренька, dszorenka, zorenka" />
    <meta name = "description" content = "Официальный сайт МБДОУ ДС Зоренька." />
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href = "/img/icons/logo.ico" rel = "shortcut icon" type = "image/x-icon" />
    <link href = "../css/style.css" rel = "stylesheet" />
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.nav.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/ajaxupload.3.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadImage(btnUpload, status, fun) {
            new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
                action: './uploads_file.php',
                name: 'uploadfile',
                onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                     if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
                        // extension is not allowed 
                        status.text('Поддерживаемые форматы JPG, PNG или GIF');
                        return false;
                    }
                    status.text('Загрузка...');
                },
                onComplete: function(file, response){
                    //On completion clear the status
                    status.text('');
                    //Add uploaded file to list
                    if(response==="success") {
                        alert("Картинка загружена.");
//                        $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="../files/img/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
                    } else {
                        alert("Ошибка загрузки картинки.");
//                        $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text('Файл не загружен' + file).addClass('error');
                    }
                    fun(file);
                }
            });
        }
        
        $(function(){
            $('#load_additional_image').click(function() {
                loadImage($('#load_additional_image'), $('.status'), function(filename) {
                    $('textarea[name=full_text]').append('&ltbr&gt&ltbr&gt&lt;img src="/files/img/'+filename+'" alt="'+filename+'"&gt;');
                });
            });
            $('#upload').click(function() {
                loadImage($('#upload'), $('.status'), function(filename) {
                    $('input[name=img_url]').val(filename);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class = "container">
  <!-- ------------Хидер------------- -->
  <?php
   require_once('../blocks/header.php');
  ?>
        <center><h1 class="h1All"><a href="/admin/index.php">Панель администратора</a></h1></center>
  <p class="txtPAll"><br>
      <form method="POST" class = "formAddAdmin">
          <label class = "lableFormAdd" for="title">
                    Заголовок<br>
                    <input type="text" name="title" class = "inputFormAdd" autofocus required>
          </label><br>
          <label class = "lableFormAdd" for="intro_text">
                   Вступительный текст<br>
                   <input type="text" name="intro_text" class = "inputFormAdd" required>
                </label><br>
                <label class = "lableFormAdd" for="full_text">
                    Текст<br>
                    <textarea name="full_text" class = "textareaFormAdd" required></textarea>
                </label><br>
                <div id="upload" class="loadImgBtn">
                    <span>Выбрать файл для основной картинки</span>
                </div>
                <div id="load_additional_image" class="loadImgBtn">
                    <span>Выбрать файл для доп. картинки</span>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="img_url">
          <!--<ul id="files" ></ul>-->
                <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Сохранить" class = "btnFormAdd">
                <span class="status"></span>
      </form>
  </p>
 </div><!-- .container -->
   <div class = "clear"></div>
  </main><!-- .content -->
  <!-- ------------Футер------------- -->
  <?php
   require_once('../blocks/footer.php');
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Весь прикол еще в том, что все работало, потом добавил перед вызовом картинки "\n" для переноса каретки на новую строку и все перестало работать. Как видите, ее нету, но все равно не работает ничего. Однако, до того, как перестало работать я менял еще много что, возможно, даже скорее всего, накосячил, но этого не вижу...

Comment: Так он так и не добавится используйте $($0).val(текст)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так он так и не добавится, используйте

```
var text = $('textarea').val();
$('textarea').val(text + 'текст');
```